# configure pppoe on wrt54gl(openwrt)

Tags: dsl, openwrt, router

I have home DSL connection from my ISP with a beetel modem at my end. I want to make my network wireless, so i bought a linksys wrt54gl and installed open-wrt on it. My ISP provides dynamic IP's with me connecting via pppoe. My question is how do I configure openwrt to work with this. Please suggest what option should I go with, or any other you recommend.

1. DSL cable-->Beetel Modem--> Wrt54gl in bridge mode with beetel modem doing the pppoe and having a DHCP server.
2. DSL cable-->Wrt54gl with wrt54gl handling the pppoe.

Is option 2 possible, can I have a setup without bringing the beetel modem in the picture at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do #2 because the wrt54gl doesn't have a DSL modem built in.  You can't plug a phone line into an Ethernet jack and have it work. However, you might be able to put the beetel DSL modem into bridge mode, letting the wrt54gl handle PPPoE, NAT, and DHCP service. That's probably the way I'd go. Do you have the ability to reconfigure the beetel modem?

Comment: I can do basic stuff on the beetel modem like enable/disable NAT DHCP or switch to bridged mode etc. Should I switch to bridged mode and disable NAT DHCP on beetel modem and handle it on openwrt. Also do I put the  modem and the openwrt router in the same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend configuring wrt as a bridge an instead of using the modem use your pc for the ppp stuff. This usually allows more flexibily in your setup and also, since these modems cannot handle a lot of connections, can support more open concurrent connections.

On the down side, if you have a lan you need the ppp server to be always up and running or else the rest of machines won't have access to the internet.